# C-Style Cast With Memory

Tags: c++, c

Here is an example of a C-Style cast that I am using:

```
*(char*)(0x0FCA41E + (0x280 * i)) = 0xFF;
```

This code is essentially a Call of Duty hack which tampers with the health of the player. By default, the value at address `0x0FCA41E` is `0x00` but changing it to `0xFF` initiates infinate health. I understand what this line of code does, but does this have to be a `char`? Can it look like this?

```
*(int*)(0x0FCA41E + (0x280 * i)) = 0xFF;
//or
*(short*)(0x0FCA41E + (0x280 * i)) = 0xFF;
```

I understand that `0xFF` is one byte of memory, like a `char`, but what would happen if I used an `int` or a `short`? Would that work?

If not, then what would be an example of using an `int` or `short` in this sense?

Thanks!

---

By the way, I made a similar post to this a few days go (incase it looks familiar) but this is a different question overall.

Comment: While the answer likely will be the same regardless, please choose 'C' or 'C++' - they are two very different languages.

Comment: The reason I put both is because I am writing this in C++ but in the past when I have mentioned `*(char*)`, people always looked at it as C and told me it is not very common in C++. But I agree.

Comment: @tonysdg I disagree. If the question is about C, tag it C. If the question is about C++, tag it C++. If the question is about both, tag it both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to what iharob said, another difference is how much memory the assignment will overwrite. In the example, using a char will overwrite a single byte with 0xFF. But if you cast it to an int, then 4 or 8 bytes (depending on the machine architecture) will be overwritten. This will result in some undefined behavior as you don't know what other values, if any, will be erased.

Comment: Technically this is already undefined behaviour, as far as C goes.

Comment: What if I had a char array? Like: `char bytes[] = { 0xFF, 0x01 }` How would I handle this? That would be 2 bytes, like a short, right? Or maybe `*(short*)(0x0FCA41E + (0x280 * i)) = 0xFF, 0x01;`

Comment: @ArchieGertsman Are you wanting to write those two bytes to consecutive locations in memory?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman First, I'm going to do a little CYA. When you start messing with memory like this you can get into big trouble, very fast. Know that you are doing this at your own risk. That being said, I think the best way of handling the array of bytes is to save a char pointer to the first location, the write the bytes via a for loop, incrementing the pointer as you walk the array. Using a short cast will likely cause you problems. First is how the final address is calculated (look up pointer arithmetic), the second is possible endian issues.